# How to add a list of enumerations in an activerecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm currently using `simple_enum` for fields like `as_enum :title, { mrs: 0, mr: 1 }` but now I need to have a list of enumerations : for example a field `categories` which may take several enumerated values. **And I don't want to make a join :)**

I looked several other gems but found nothing. Is there a simple solution for this ?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

We often use a simple [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) for these kinds of values.

Comment: thanks, is there some gem to generate the accessors and integrate with a form builder (I'm not a very experienced ruby developer...) ?

Comment: hum... found https://github.com/grosser/bitfields and https://github.com/pjb3/has-bit-field ; will investigate...